# How to pass a value from a page to other without POST

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

Im trying to pass a value from one page to another by using PHP.
I have a session file that have the all variables but i can´t pass one of them and I don´t know why.
I´m passing some values from a foreach too because the page its a "change" or an "edit" page to some players from a game.
My first page where I have the name is this one:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4R9A.jpg
The code of this page is (the part that I want to pass to the other page is the variable "nome" on the H2 -> inside the body):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    //Este ficheiro, APÓS LOGIN (autenticação) com sucesso; apresentará uma página de boas-vindas
    include ('session.php');
?>
<html >
<head>
    <title>DSE | Menu</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_welcome.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagens/favicon.ico" />
    <!-- CSS para a tabela com pesquisa funcionar -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="menu" tabindex="0">
    <div class="smartphone-menu-trigger"></div>
  <header class="avatar">
        <img src="imagens/LOGO_DSE.png" />
        <!-- Apresenta o nome do user após o login -->
        <h2>Bem-vindo(a), <?php echo $nome;?>!</h2>

  </header>
```

The page that I want it to appear is this one: https://imgur.com/a/C68lQpN
The code of the page is:

```
<?php
    include "functions.php";
    $idutente=$_GET ['id'];
    $nome=$nome;
    $tasks = DBRead3($idutente);

    foreach($tasks as $cl)
        {
            $cl_nome=$cl['nome'];
            $cl_data_nascimento=$cl['data_nascimento'];
            $cl_peso=$cl['peso'];
            $cl_altura=$cl['altura'];
            $cl_tipo_sangue=$cl['tipo_sangue'];
            $cl_alergias=$cl['alergias'];
            $cl_doencas=$cl['doencas'];
            $cl_telefone=$cl['telefone'];
            $cl_morada=$cl['morada'];
            $cl_notas=$cl['notas'];
            $cl_seguro=$cl['seguro'];
            $cl_identificador=$cl['identificador'];
        } ?>
<html >
<head>
    <title>DSE | Menu</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_welcome.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagens/favicon.ico" />
    <!-- CSS para a tabela com pesquisa funcionar -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="menu" tabindex="0">
    <div class="smartphone-menu-trigger"></div>
  <header class="avatar">
        <img src="imagens/LOGO_DSE.png" />
        <!-- Apresenta o nome do user após o login -->
        <h2>Bem-vindo(a), <?php echo $nome;?>!</h2>

  </header>
```

I´m calling the value on the top of the page, and using it again on the body inside the H2 tag, but it´s not working.
The foreach here is to call the variables that i want to be edited...
Does anyone know how to help me?

Comment: you are starting a session after you send text to the browser. Sessions must be started before any output

Comment: So you should put `include ('session.php');` at the very top of the page

Comment: I can´t put the include because I already did it on the function file, and if I do it, gives me this error: [11-Apr-2019 15:40:23 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare DBConnect() (previously declared in /home/rpvrtvpt/public_html/DSE/functions.php:6) in /home/rpvrtvpt/public_html/DSE/functions.php on line 8

Comment: then use `require_once` instead

Comment: Don´t work either, same error

Comment: you have to use `require_once` everywhere you used to use `include`

Comment: But I dind´t require it on my function file.. how can i overcome that?

Comment: Still not working